# Reactjs: On clicking title display blog post contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm trying to make a blogsite using MERN stack. So here I have my Blogs component which fetches all blogposts from db and display as shown below

[image]

here's the react code for the above pic

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import BlogDetails from "./BlogDetails";

const Blogs = () => {
    const [blogPost, setPosts] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
     const fetchBlog = async ()=>{
      const blogsData = await axios('http://localhost:4000/blogs')
      const blogsFetched = blogsData.data
      console.log(blogsFetched);
      setPosts(blogsFetched)
     }
     fetchBlog()   
    },[])
    return ( 
        <div className="blogs content">
          <h2>All Blogs</h2>
          { blogPost.map((post)=>(
            <div key={post._id}>
              <a className="single" href={post._id}>
              <h3 className="title" >{post.title}</h3>
              <p className="snippet">{post.snippet}</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          ))
          }
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Blogs;
```

I want to show **a particular blog post in detail when I click on its title from the above page**.
On clicking the title, those details will be passed as props to another component named **BlogDetails** and will be rendered. The part where I'm stuck is routing to BlogDetails component with blogpost id. Is there any way in which on clicking the title, I can use Route to render BlogDetails component?
Please help

Comment: you can push url to history => `const history = useHistory(); history.push("detailurl")`

Comment: Are you using react router? If you were, you can just use the useHistory hook, get the history object and do history.push("/blog/{id}") with the specific blog id. 
Then on the subsequent page, you can use useLocation and get the pathname if you want to rely solely on the url.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using react-router, you could do something like:

```
const history = useHistory();
.
.
.
<div onClick={() => history.push(`/blog/${post.id}`)}>
  <h3 className="title">{post.title}</h3>
</div>
```

And then your router will render your component which you specified to be rendered for the `/blog` route. In that route, you can fetch the url using useLocation and then parse the id by splitting the url.

```
const { pathName } = useLocation(); // also from react-router
```

Alternatively (and more elegantly), you can push pieces of state when you do history.push, like:

```
...onClick={() => history.push(`/blog${post.id}`, { blogId: ${post.id}})}
```

Then again in your subsequently rendered component you use `useLocation` to get the state passed:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use route for BlogDetail component

add BlogDetail link in BrowserRouter

```
<Route path={'url'} render={(props) => <BlogDetail/>}/>
```

In Blogs component use Link of react router dom and then use this link on title in render html like this

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 { blogPost.map((post)=>(
            <div key={post._id}>
              <a className="single" href={post._id}>
              
              <Link to={{
                    pathname:'url', // this will be your url of BlogDetail
                    state: post //if you want post object detail in next component
              }}>
                 <h3 className="title" >{post.title}</h3>
               </Link>
              <p className="snippet">{post.snippet}</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          ))
          }
```